# How to handle multi-typed variable untupling?

Tags: sql, tuples, clickhouse

I want to convert instance to an array in ClickHouse. It can be `string` (in case of only one elem provided) or `tuple`.

The following statement crashes, if only one id is provided:

```sql
array(untuple(ids))
```

How to handle it carefully?

Comment: Instance of what data type? To array of what elements of what data type? Please, edit your question with some sample data and the result desired on it.